# Tesseract 3 (OCR) - .NET Wrapper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wrapper, tesseract

http://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/

I am having a problem getting Tesseract to work in my Visual Studio 2010 projects. I have tried console and winforms and both have the same outcome. I have come across a dll by someone else who claims to have it working in `VS2010`:

http://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/issues/detail?id=1

I am adding a reference to the dll which can be found in the attached to post 64 from the website above. Every time I build my project I get an `AccessViolationException` saying that an attempt was made to read or write protected memory.

```
public void StartOCR()
{
    const string language = "eng";
    const string TessractData = @"C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\tessdata\";

    using (TesseractProcessor processor = new TesseractProcessor())
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(fileName) as Bitmap)
        {
            if (processor.Init(TessractData, language, (int)eOcrEngineMode.OEM_DEFAULT))
            {
                string text = processor.Recognize(bmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The access violation exception always points to `if (processor.Init(TessractData, language, (int)eOcrEngineMode.OEM_DEFAULT))`. I've seen a few suggestions to make sure the solution platform is set to `x86` in the configuration manager and that the tessdata folder location is finished with trailing slash, to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: can you please share your full implementation? I think I am reading conflicting instructions on how to set this up.

Comment: Cannot take the credit but this worked for me: Replace 'eng.traineddata' in the tessdata folder with this
http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=eng.traineddata.gz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appeared to be the contents of the tessdata folder that was causing the problem. Obtained the tessdata folder from the first link and all is now working.

Answer (score 2):

I have just completed a project with tesseract engine 3. i think, there is a bug in the engine, that need to be rectified. What i Did to remove "AccessViolationError" is, add "\tessdata" to the real tessdata directory string. I don't know why, but the engine seems to be truncating the innermost directory in the Tessdata path.

Just made Full OCR package (Dlls+Tessdata(english)) that works with .net framework 4.

Comment: True! Folder is located in "e:\tessdata", and variable definition is `const string tessractData = @"e:\tessdata\tessdata";`

Answer (score 0):

If somebody has the same problem and advice with trailing slash doesn't work, try... TWO ending slashes! Seriosly. It works for me.

```
if (processor.Init(@".\tessdata\\", "eng", (int)eOcrEngineMode.OEM_DEFAULT))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your problem relates to stability issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/issues/231). On the official [site](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) there is a recommendation to use previous stable release 2.4.1. You can install it from nuget.org via the package manager command: `Install-Package Tesseract -Version 2.4.1`