# Get numbers of processed pictures

Tags: c#, image, ocr

With this code I can make a picture black and white. But how can I get the numbers from the picture into a label?

```
Bitmap BMP = new Bitmap("H:\\pelak.jpg");
Color col;
//int r, g, b, rgb;
byte blue, green, red;

for (int i = 0; i < Int32.Parse(BMP.Width.ToString()); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Int32.Parse(BMP.Height.ToString()); j++)
    {
        col = BMP.GetPixel(i, j);
        blue = col.B;
        green = col.G;
        red = col.R;

        if (red < 128)
        {
            BMP.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0));
        }
        if (red >= 128)
        {
            BMP.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));
        }
    }
}
pictureBox2.Image = BMP;
```

Comment: Number from picture? or total number of pictures processed?

Comment: Which numbers you  trying to achieve from picture ???

Comment: Why `int.Parse(int.ToString())` ?

Comment: Are you looking for an OCR Library ? Define more precisely the number, if it's inside a pic, please add a sample pic. Also, avoid using .ToString/Parse on Width and Height. If it's not the correct type you can Convert it in one step.

Comment: i wanna get plate of a car...

Comment: What does that have to do with it?!

Comment: for example this picture:
http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=HN.607988784524493902&w=250&h=75&c=7&rs=1&pid=1.7
how to get the Numbers in this Picture into TextBox?

Answer (score 1):

OCR is not available in the .Net Framework, you are looking for an [Optical character recognition (OCR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) library. Or you may try to implement it but the task is hard.

You may try [tesseractdotnet](http://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/) or find another library depending on your needs.

Comment: According to this link Tessnet2 depends on a buggy version with serious memory leaks. A version 3 as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067002/tesseract-3-ocr-net-wrapper) seems more advisable..

Comment: What to do?what not to do My Friends?
how can i get the source code?

Comment: @ILiya, click on tesseractdotnet link then `Tutorial` you may also try the sample application. Once you understand the Library, use your skills on your applicaiton. Otherwise try Google to find another OCR .Net component that may be easier to use.

Comment: tesseractdotnet :
403. That’s an error.
Request not allowed from your country

Comment: @ILiya It works in my country. You may try to find another Library.

Comment: i want Something like this:[link](http://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/anpr/screenshots/gui1.jpg)