# How I can implement Tesseract OCR in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, ocr, tesseract

I want to implement Tesseract OCR in my project, and use it. But i don't know how this works.

I know that Tesseract OCR takes an image and converts to simple text. What do I need to do that? What do I need to download?

I am using Visual Basic 2013 Express Edition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tesseract 3 (OCR) - .NET Wrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067002/tesseract-3-ocr-net-wrapper) - @dylansamuel please search this site - there are other answers and questions that might be better suited then just this plain one, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [.Net wrapper for tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) project.